# Image Not Touching the Side of Body

Tags: html, css, image, border, margins

To start off, here is a link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndmxcj80/6/) with an example of the problem I'm having. What I want is the banner that is at the top of the screen to perfectly fill in the header. I'm not having much luck with getting CSS to work with me.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="http://rockstartemplate.com/blogheaders/bannerdesign2.jpg" alt="Banner">

    <h1>Sample Text<br></h1>
  </header>

  <main>
  Oh boy some sample text
  </main>

  <footer>
    More Sample Text
  </footer>
</body>
```

And:

```
html, body  {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;

  width: 950px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 18px 9px black;

  background-color: white;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #800000;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0em;
  padding-left: 2em;

  background-color: grey;
}

main {
  clear: left;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
}

footer { 
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove padding-left from this css:

```
header {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #800000;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0em;
  padding-left: 2em;

  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Won't let me accept an answer yet, but thank you! It worked! I've been trying to Google this for the past hour or two. Didn't the padding I added did that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

html

```
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="http://rockstartemplate.com/blogheaders/bannerdesign2.jpg" alt="Banner">

    <h1>Sample Text<br></h1>
  </header>

  <main>
  Oh boy some sample text
  </main>

  <footer>
    More Sample Text
  </footer>
</body>
```

css

```
html, body  {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;

  width: 950px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 9px 18px 9px black;

  background-color: white;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #800000;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

header img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;

}

main {
  clear: left;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
}

footer { 
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Ran it in jfiddle. While it made it so it wasn't sticking out, it still isn't touching both sides. Is there something I'm either writing incorrectly or not adding to make it work how I want?

Comment: I do. I want it to stick to the bottom as well. Another comment fixed the problem with the right and left sides, but there's still space on the bottom. I'm unsure if you can see it in jfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ndmxcj80/6/ The link in case the top one doesn't work.

Comment: So with the z-index, you put the gray background behind the body?

Comment: if you are trying to get rid of that little grey line, the simplest way is to remove the background-color from the header.

Comment: No no, I used z-indez 1 in header and z-index -1 in the image, so the image stay behind the text

Answer (score 0):

```
body {width: 1000px;}
```

or

```
img {max-width:900px;}
```

just adjust css to make img looks in center.